# Apache solr data import handler logs on jetty container

Tags: solr, jetty, dataimporthandler

I am using solr 4.6 for fetching records from sql server using data import handler.But while fetching i am getting error and the reason for error is one of my field is of LatLong type.So when My sql latlong field contains wrong value for eg 23.454,545454  As u can see longitude value i.e 545454 is wrong so solr dih gives error. I want know where solr keeps these error logs. I am using jetty container for solr.

Comment: check at /opt/solr/logs...

Comment: here is a link https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJetty

Comment: Hey Abhijit, do i need to mention somewhere log path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dsolr.solr.home=/opt/solr/solr $JAVA_OPTIONS"
JETTY_HOME=/opt/solr
JETTY_USER=solr
JETTY_LOGS=/opt/solr/logs
```

All of these settings are important. In particular, not setting JETTY_LOGS would lead jetty to attempt (and fail) to place request logs in /home/solr/logs.

go through the link

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJetty

Comment: thnx for reply...one more question..can i configure solr dih to write only those errors while importing to a file which i specify?